# Trigger alarm based on a rate-limit on S3 GetObject and DeleteObject requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudtrail

Recently, one of my AWS accounts got compromised, fortunately we were able to change all secure information in time. To avoid recurrence of such a situation the first thing to do would be to have a process in place for secret info management.

That said, I would also want to trigger a cloudwatch alarm in a case where multiple download or delete is taking place **from inside my AWS account**.

I have come across solutions like

1. AWS WAF
2. Have a CDN in place
3. Trigger a lambda function on an event in S3

Solutions #1 & #2 are not serving to my requirement as they throttle requests coming from outside of AWS. Once it is implemented at S3 level, it will automatically throttle both inside and outside requests.

In solution #3 I could not get a hold of multiple objects requested by an IP in my lambda function, when a threshold time limit and threshold number of file is crossed.

Is raising an alarm by rate-limiting at S3 level a possibility?

Comment: Do you want to create an alarm or rate limit requests? Please limit your question to one question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no rate limit provided by AWS on S3 directly, but you can implement alarms over SNS Topics with CloudTrails.

Unless you explicitly require anyone in your team to remove the objects in your S3 bucket, you shouldn't provide anyone access. The following are some idea you can follow:

**Implement the least privilege access**

- You can block the access to remove the objects on the IAM User
  level, so no-one will be able to remove any items.
- You can modify the Bucket policy to provide DeleteObject Access to
  specific users/roles as conditions.

**Enable multi-factor authentication (MFA) Delete**

- MFA Delete can help prevent accidental bucket deletions. If MFA
  Delete is not enabled, any user with the password of a sufficiently
  privileged root or IAM user could permanently delete an Amazon S3
  object.
- MFA Delete requires additional authentication for either of the
  following operations:
  Changing the versioning state of your bucket
  Permanently deleting an object version.

**S3 Object Lock**

S3 Object Lock enables you to store objects using a "Write Once Read Many" (WORM) model. S3 Object Lock can help prevent accidental or inappropriate deletion of data. For example, you could use S3 Object Lock to help protect your AWS CloudTrail logs.

**Amazon Macie with Amazon S3**

Macie uses machine learning to automatically discover, classify, and protect sensitive data in AWS. Macie recognizes sensitive data such as personally identifiable information (PII) or intellectual property. It provides you with dashboards and alerts that give visibility into how this data is being accessed or moved.

---

You can learn more about the best Security Practices with S3.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/secure-s3-resources/